# When get the swf address, how to show the flash with the flashplayer again?

Tags: javascript, cocoa, safari

I used the cocoa of MAC to develop a plugin with safari , I used the method is : changed the plugin's MIME TYPES is application/x-shockwave-flash and extensions is swf, so when safari  lanched , it will add my plugin , but Now have a problem : when the safari page showing , the swf embed it don't show , because I don't know the method of showing swf with adobe flashplayer again. And how to implement the method to show the swf with flashplayer after the safari page show all swf files in it ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the swf embed it don't show , because I don't know the method of showing swf with adobe flashplayer again.

There is no way to do this except to handle only `application/futuresplash` (the type no-one uses), then switch the element to `application/x-shockwave-flash` so that Flash Player will handle it.

That's what ClickToFlash does, which means there is no way for you to make your plug-in compatible with ClickToFlash. In fact, it sounds like you're trying to do the same thing as ClickToFlash, so why not contribute features to that project instead?

Comment: yes, it is what ClickToFlash does. In fact I want to develop a plugin  that can get all the swf address with safari. but I don't like the SIMBL , so I refer to the ClickToFlash. and set the plugin MIME TYPE is application/x-shockwave-flash, and then safari can load my plugin, if have some methods that to relove my plugin's problem I don't want to refer to the ClickToFlash . can you some methods or advice about it ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Now I can change the type to application/futuresplash, so when safari lauched,the swf can show a map:plugin- click to load. But this is not my purpose.because I want to save these swf in my location and show it in a webview of program. And this webview show the same map. I think the reason is : when I get a swf address and change the type safari use adobe flashplayer to handle it . but when user click the map then load that plugin. but how to show the swf normal after I got the address? can I remove the  MIME TYPES with my info.plist using func or some program methods ? How to do ? Thank you!